# Real notification/push notification system in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, notifications

I am building a college project in which I need to implement a notification system like Facebook as in lets say there are two users logged in. When a user comments/likes another user's post then a database entry is made for both liking and notification. At the same time post author should also get notification of the like/comment event and notification icon should be updated. Project is built using PHP, Jquery, AJAX and likes. Can anyone tell me how to implement this in real time without bottlenecks? Reference links or code or tutorials would be much appreciated.

Comment: you might want to look into websockets

Comment: @Calimero I did search for it and still looking. No good resource found yet.

Comment: I guess pull-based is more based on php and jquery, but to keep the script and payload small, maybe you can consider having a column for like/comment/notification, and this column only returns true or false for the purpose of notifying the user during a js->php query, only upon user selecting to read the notification then perform the full query and at the same time update the user row notification column to 0, otherwise it is only a simple select on a single column(notication = 1 WHERE user_id...) for js to do the background query only every 500ms or 1000ms. for push-based, its quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

These system built on PHP are anyway PULL Based Notifications and not Push based Notifications.

The logic is you try to query the database as frequently as possible keeping the tradeoff between Load on client side and Realtimeliness.

For ex:

```
function pullNotifications(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"notificationFetch.php",
        success: function(data){
            // Parse data
            // Check new notifications if any
            // If yes notify user

            //....

            setTimeout(function(){
                pullNotifications();
            },1000); // Calling it again after every one second
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Running a script or AJAX call to check for new notifications after a specific interval would be inefficient, Right?
Is there any better efficient way?

Comment: I think that would be too complicated for your `college project`

Comment: Yes but I want to implement or learn a better way to do this. I appreciate your answer. However, I still seek a better alternative.